# Какой род у Торонто?

Tags: предлоги, существительные, род

Верно ли составлено предложение? Почему не средний род?

> **Торонто** всегда **славился** своими многочисленными парками...

Answer (score 2):

С подлежащим, выраженным заимствованным несклоняемым словом, сказуемое согласуется в соответствии с его грамматическим родом, например:

г)      ...Миссисипи (река) **разлилась**; Капри (остров) **спал**; Батуми (город) **вырос** за последние годы; Рядом шла нарядная Прадо (улица) (Маяковский)
[Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html)

**Торо́нто** — крупнейший **город** Канады, административный центр провинции Онтарио. Существительное **город** мужского рода, поэтому "Торонто славился".

Предложение составлено верно.